(Measure) Integrability Requirement in Sobolev Space
I am interested in the following: Let $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ denote a Sobolev space on $\Omega$, i.e. for $f \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ it holds that, up to the $k$-th derivative, $f$ is $L^p$-integrable. So $f, f^{(1)}, ...,f^{(k)} \in L^p(\Omega)$. (Compare to wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space).
Is there a problem with defining $W^{k,p}_{\mu}(\Omega)$, s.t. for $f \in W^{k,p}_{\mu}(\Omega)$ it holds that $f, f^{(1)}, ...,f^{(k)} \in L^p(\mu, \Omega)$, where $L^p(\mu, \Omega)$ denotes the space of functions whose $p$-th power is $\mu$-integrable. Intuitively, I think this is a natural extension/variation but I was surprised when I was not able to find something like this on the Wikipedia page and also not in the parts of the book I am currently reading.

You can consider Sobolev space on metric measure spaces. A simple google search comes up with this, e.g.: https://homepages.uc.edu/~shanmun/book.pdf

A special case of changing the measure are weighted Sobolev spaces, say when $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure. But warning that in general the Sobolev embeddings for example might not remain true.
